# Is it possible to use Actions in an interface with add/remove?

Tags: c#, events, interface, delegates, wrapper

Basically I'm trying to do [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with Actions. I need to do something like that as opposed to a property because in at least one of the concretions an Action from another class is referenced- since you can only add/remove to Actions and not actually return them I would need to wrap it in an add/remove rather than a get.

```
interface Whatever
{
    Action MyAction { get; }
}

class WhateverConcretion : Whatever
{
    Action MyAction
    {
        get { return SomeLibraryClass.StaticAction; }
    }        
}
```

My project depends on platform specific libraries so I planned to make my classes depend on an interface for a wrapper class and the library for each platform would be wrapped in its own class- which worked fine until I came to wrapping Actions.

Comment: Have you tried it?  This works fine, as written.  Your link is about events, not just using properties for delegates.

Comment: Looks like what you wrote ought to work fine. I think you're thinking of events - actions are ordinary C# objects just like any other.

Comment: You have made ***properties*** of type `Action`. Properties have either one or two accessors, called `get` and/or `set`. To make ***events*** instead, include the keyword `event` just before the type (`Action`). Events have two accessors called `add` and `remove`. Here's an example: `public event Action MyEvent { add { ... } remove { ... } }`. The type `Action` is a delegate type and can therefore be used for an event. Since it has return type `void` and has no type parameters that are contravariant, I would say it is a suitable type for an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a wrapper, it normal to publish the members of the inner class to the outside world with preferably the same names and types of that members. To wrap methods is easy: just make another method which calls te methods of the inner class, passing its parameters and return its value(s). For properties the same: create the property, with getters and setters as desired and call the getters and setters of the properties of the inner instance.

Now for evens it is the same thing. Create an event in the wrapper class and redirect its calls the the inner class:

```
public event Action MyAction
{
    add 
    { 
         SomeLibraryClass.StaticAction += value;
    }
    remove
    { 
         SomeLibraryClass.StaticAction -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `add` and `remove` accessors have return type `void`, so the `return` statement is not correct as it stands.